# create database with current dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm building a database for demonstrating software. The date fields in the database need to be current as its a script that will constantly rebuild so dates will always be current to the present date. However the `DATE()` functions don't appear to be working correctly.

As an example, I'm importing a mySql script on the command line into a database and this is one of the tables that is getting inserted

```
-- Table structure for table `tasks`
--

CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `funeral_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deceased_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_type_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `courtesy_call` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q_accepted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q_mailed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q_returned` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `user_created_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_modified_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tasks`
--

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `funeral_id`, `deceased_id`, `contact_id`, `task_type_id`, `assigned_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `notes`, `courtesy_call`, `q_accepted`, `q_mailed`, `q_returned`, `status_id`, `user_created_id`, `created`, `user_modified_id`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '39', NULL, 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)', NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1, '2016-05-27 16:40:17', NULL, '2016-05-27 16:40:17');
```

I want to build the `end_date` field as today plus four days, and the function `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)` returns `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Also, anywhere I've tried to use `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` returns the same values `0000-00-00 00:00:00`
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a small typo.

You are trying to insert 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)' but the quotes around the function name translate that into a string instead, so it fires a warning and inserts 0000-00-00

Try removing the quotes

```
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `funeral_id`, `deceased_id`, `contact_id`, `task_type_id`, `assigned_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `notes`, `courtesy_call`, `q_accepted`, `q_mailed`, `q_returned`, `status_id`, `user_created_id`, `created`, `user_modified_id`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '39', NULL, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1, '2016-05-27 16:40:17', NULL, '2016-05-27 16:40:17');
```

also it should work with CURDATE()

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from DATE_ADD(..).

You can also use `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)`   or `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)`

```
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `funeral_id`, `deceased_id`, `contact_id`, `task_type_id`, `assigned_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `notes`, `courtesy_call`, `q_accepted`, `q_mailed`, `q_returned`, `status_id`, `user_created_id`, `created`, `user_modified_id`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '39', NULL, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1, '2016-05-27 16:40:17', NULL, '2016-05-27 16:40:17');
```

You can refer the Mysql [Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) documentation for details:

Comment: It gives the same result

Comment: @NishuTayal: Your answer did not correct the mistake. Look into [PerroVerd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37746655/767881).

Comment: @RavinderReddy : ohh yeah.. typo left in the query. corrected it